# how to set left and top postion for jquery ui dialog dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have a problem in setting `left` and `top` position for jquery ui dialog.

I have read some where position can be set like this `position:[100,200]` where 100 is left value and 200 is top value.

in my project i need to remember the user last `position` where they will `drag` the dialog and open there itself, that is why i used setInterval here, to demonstrate user changing dialog position.

**Question:** i want to set dialog `left` and `top` position between those positions i,e (max 200, max 300).

**Note:** as pointed out by **@RoryMcCrossan**,  how to remember its last position and show any following modals in the same position(exactly i need)

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 5 + 1)) + 5;
  var top1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 - 5 + 1)) + 5;
  var positionArray = [left, top1];
  var positionObj = {
    postion: positionArray
  };
  
  console.clear();
  console.log(positionObj);
  
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: true,
    maxHeight: $(window).height() - 40,
    maxWidth: $(window).width() - 40,
    resizable: true,
    positionObj, //position:[left,top],
  });

  $("#dialog").dialog('open');
}, 1200);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog">
  <p>My dialog</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So to be clear, you're asking 1) how to restrict the draggable position of a modal and 2) how to remember its last position and show any following modals in the same position. Is that right? You should also note that in any case a `setInterval()` is not the right thing to be using here and should be removed ASAP.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yeh, whatever you said as point **2)** i'm expecting same result, just i'm simulating position with random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var myInt;

  function createPos() {
    return [Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 5 + 1)) + 5, Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 - 5 + 1)) + 5];
  }

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: true,
    maxHeight: $(window).height() - 40,
    maxWidth: $(window).width() - 40,
    modal: true,
    resizable: true,
    position: createPos(),
    open: function() {
      myInt = setInterval(function() {
        var posArr = createPos();
        console.clear();
        console.log(posArr);
        $(".ui-dialog").css({
          left: posArr[0] + "px",
          top: posArr[1] + "px"
        });
      }, 1200);
    },
    close: function() {
      clearInterval(myInt);
    }
  }).dialog("open");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog">
  <p>My dialog</p>
</div>
```

The Option `position` can be changed after opening, yet it is not read. You will want to adjust the CSS `left` and `top` of the `ui-dialog` parent class.

You can also use `.animate()`:

```js
$(function() {
  var myInt;

  function createPos() {
    return [Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 5 + 1)) + 5, Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 - 5 + 1)) + 5];
  }

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: true,
    maxHeight: $(window).height() - 40,
    maxWidth: $(window).width() - 40,
    modal: true,
    resizable: true,
    open: function() {
      myInt = setInterval(function() {
        var posArr = createPos();
        console.clear();
        console.log(posArr);
        $(".ui-dialog").animate({
          left: posArr[0] + "px",
          top: posArr[1] + "px"
        }, 1000);
      }, 1200);
    },
    close: function() {
      clearInterval(myInt);
    }
  }).dialog("open");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog">
  <p>My dialog</p>
</div>
```